# OpenJPA treats field with oneToMany Mapping as a Blob

Tags: java, database, jpa, annotations

I'm having a serious issue with JPA's implementation of OneToMany relationships and I'm looking for a reasonable workaround.  The issue is that JPA appears to get confused reading it's @OneToMany annotation and returns:

> "Flea.dog" declares a column that is not compatible with the expected type "blob".

Flea.dog is a numeric field. The issue appears to be a known bug:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1481

The issue is created as follows: I have two entities Dog and Flea, A Dog has many fleas represented by a dog_id in the Flea table. These entities are mapped to tables with different names Dog is mapped to Madra, Flea is mapped to feithidi.

The tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE madra (dogid BIGINT, name varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (dogid));
CREATE TABLE feithidi (fleaid BIGINT, dogid BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (fleaid));
```

I'm using H2 for the example, though I've had the same issue on Oracle.

The entities are as follows:

```
@Entity(name="feithidi")
Flea{
  @Id
  long fleaid;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="dogid", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=true)
  private Dog dog;

}
```

and

```
@Entity(name="madra")
Dog{
  @Id
  long dogid;
  String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="dog")
  private Set<Flea> fleas;

}
```

The full exception I am returned is:

> ( org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Flea.dog" declares a column that is not compatible with the expected type "blob".

If anyone has a work around or can see an obvious error on my part I'd be grateful for some feedback.

Comment: OpenJPA isn't the only implementation of JPA.  You could try another free one, like [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/), and see if it has the same problem.

Comment: I'd love to, however my employer mandates OpenJPA.  I know this works fine in hibernate, and I'd assume EclipseLink

Answer (score 7):

Got the same error message because I had forgot to put the Dog-entity in the persistence.xml.